# Get all duplicate rows between two datetimes.

Tags: sql, t-sql

I was recently asked the following question during an interview:

Return all duplicate rows in a table that are between two different 
dates / times.

My best guess is:

```
SELECT *, 
COUNT(LogDate) AS NumOccurrences
FROM LogTable
WHERE LogDate > "SomeDate" 
AND LogDate < "SomeDate"
GROUP BY LogDate
HAVING ( COUNT(LogDate) > 1 )
```

Am I in the ballpark? Any thoughts on the right answer?

Thanks.

Comment: You can't use `SELECT *` with a `GROUP BY LogDate`. Otherwise it looks fine. You could have also used `BETWEEN`. You may also need to use `<=` and `>=` to have inclusive dates.

Comment: Duplicate on all fields ? On LogDate only ?

Comment: `duplicate` is more than 1 or exact two?

Comment: @sgeddes - the interviewer didn't say. I suppose he would say "OK" if I asked.

Comment: @CodeSherpa Curious, what position were you applying for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to count(*) in the select (not as your question is formulated at least).

All fields in the select must be in the GROUP BY clause (but you can have more in the GROUP BY than in the SELECT, of course)

```
SELECT field1, field2, LogDate
FROM LogTable
WHERE LogDate BETWEEN "SomeDate" AND "SomeOtherDate"
GROUP BY field1, field2, LogDate
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: Beat me to it. Worth noting that for this to work you would need to include all fields field 1..field n available in the table.

Comment: Would `BETWEEN` be inclusive?

Comment: Thanks Raphael, this is the easiest to understand for me. Looks like I was reasonably close.

Comment: @CodeSherpa Sure. But your usage of GROUP BY seems to come from Mysql. This is not ANSI, and almost all others DBMS won't let you do this.

Comment: @njk hard to say without more precision : see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187922.aspx , point D.

Comment: In that case it would have to be `BETWEEN 'StartDate' and 'EndDate 23:59:59'`

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus What do you mean by "your usage of GROUP BY seems to come from mySQL"? In mySQL this is a valid syntax or what?

Comment: @gotqn a bad idea (my opinion), but a valid syntax, yes.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus thanks for sharing this... I have never used mySQL but find it kind of strange this will work there.